# Tkinter: Cannot scroll frame inside Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have a frame inside of a Canvas with a scrollbar. I want to scroll inside that frame (ie use the middle button of my mouse).

[This answer to another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter#3092341) should contain working code, but it is not.

How can I get this example to work?

Comment: You want to use the mouse scroll to scroll the frame

Answer (score 0):

For what I could understand from *I want to scroll inside that frame (ie use the middle button of my mouse).* You want to use the mouse wheel to scroll the frame right?

You can use `<MouseWheel>` virtual event to scroll the canvas and ultimately the frame.

```
<canvas>.create_window((0,0),window=<frame>,anchor='nw')
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    <canvas>.yview_scroll(-1*int(event.delta/120), "units")   
<canvas>.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
```

Comment: I also have a scrollable Listbox for which I did not have to setup any event and the mouse wheel works. Shouldn't the code in the link work as is? I was thinking that `onFrameConfigure` would make the mouse wheel scroll the frame.